# Selenium web driver Action Chain Send Keys (Key.CTRL+"U") is not working as expected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

https://sec.report/Document/0000070858-20-000061/bac-20200923.htm

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains 

driver.get("https://sec.report/Document/0000070858-20-000061/bac-20200923.htm")

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "U")

*Trying to get commented lines before HTML Code starts - "Workiva"*
```

My expectation is to view the source code of web page in a new tab and then extract it from there. But With Action Chain command - Ctrl + U is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

instead of `send_keys` for control, you would need to do `keys_down`

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://sec.report/Document/0000070858-20-000061/bac-20200923.htm")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys(str('\u0055')).perform()
```

or if you just want to see the source code which CTRL + U shows you, you might use wanna use the below code :

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://sec.report/Document/0000070858-20-000061/bac-20200923.htm")

view_source_code = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
print(view_source_code)
```

Comment: @P Krishnama Naidu  : Do you want to read the source code of the page ? if yes then i have updated a new block of code. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I checked your first solution with actionChains, I didn't see the source when tested. And coming to 2nd solution of viewing the source code, I am specifically looking for COMMENTED line of code before the HTML code start as below:  "<?xml version="1.0" ?><!--XBRL Document Created with Wdesk from Workiva--><!--Copyright 2020 Workiva-->". driver.page_source() also gives us the source code but the content am looking for is before the HTML code start. Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see no wait / delay etc. between the

```
driver.get("https://sec.report/Document/0000070858-20-000061/bac-20200923.htm")
```

and

```
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "U")
```

So I guess your "not working as expected" occurs because the page still not loaded when you applying the

```
actionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "U")
```

In case the solution above doesn't work please try the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"u")
```

Comment: I saw the page was loaded by then the code started executing send_Keys command. I tried with some delay as well, still no change in result.

Comment: I see. Please try additional resolution I added

Answer (score 0):

Just Think about the operation , you are holding Control Key then press U, Same way We will automate that, Here instead of only send keys we need to use key_up and key_down also.

key_down(): keyboard key needs to press it down.

key_up(): The key which pressed using the Key_down() method, doesn’t get released automatically, so key_up() method is used to release the key explicitly.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('U').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Comment: Tried this @Amit Kumar Santra, didn't get commented lines (see comments before HTML code start) am looking for.